# How to set auto height to Material UI DataGrid using row slot?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the "row" slot in MUI DataGrid, but the table height not auto adjust

I can see all results

[Greater than mid responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOB7H.png)

But lower than mid, I can't see more than 4 results because the height table is wrong

[Lower than mid responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcSuu.png)

I tried `autoHeigh & getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}`

This is my row slot

```
row: rowData => (
    <Card key={rowData.row.id}>
        <CardContent>
            <Grid container>
                {
                    rowData.visibleColumns.map((col, index) => (
                        <Grid item xs={12} key={index}>
                            <Box
                                sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}
                            >
                                <Box>{ col.headerName }</Box>
                                <Box>
                                    {
                                        col.renderCell
                                            ? col.renderCell(rowData)
                                            : col.valueGetter
                                              ? col.valueGetter({...rowData, api: gridApiRef.current })
                                              : rowData.row[col.field]
                                    }
                                </Box>
                             </Box>
                         </Grid>
                     ))
                 }
             </Grid>
        </CardContent>
    </Card>
),
```